# Jquery cant modify variable on ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have code that loads content by ajax if user scrolls to specific part of page.
In order to avoid loading content many times i created boolean variable that shoudl switch upon ajax complete and stop function from executing next time.

```
 $( document ).scroll(function() {
switch = true;
if (switch){
if ($(window).scrollTop()>($("div").offset().top)){

                $.ajax({
                  url: "ajax.php",
                  data: "data",
                }).success(function(data) {
                  $('div').append(data);
                 switch = false;
                });
}
}       
});
```

However i cannot modify this variable that way, function fires multipe times and `switch` is always true.

Comment: Try making it a global var (`window.switch`).

Answer (score 0):

`switch` is a keyword so you can't use it as a variable name.

Also the logic you have used is wrong, you need to create the variable outside of the scroll handler so that every call to the handler will get the same instance, also the flag should be set to false when you start the ajax request and should be set to true when the request completes(use always/complete handler so both success and failure will be handled)

```
var flag = true;
$(document).scroll(function () {
    if (flag) {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > ($("div").offset().top)) {
            flag = false;//ajax request in progress so don't load again
            $.ajax({
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: "data",
            }).success(function (data) {
                $('div').append(data);
            }).always(function () {
                flag = true;//request completed so load again
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Why cant i declare variable inside scroll function?

Comment: @czyzkowskiczyzkowski then in every call to the handler the variable will be created and set to true... so there is no meaning to having it